# Sending email as html

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email-formats

```
Dim objMail As New Mail.MailMessage("no-reply@mywebsite.com", ToEmail, "Password Reset", body)
```

...and the problem is that the message is sent as pure text including the `<br>` tags within the body

How could i send the email as html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
objMail.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this in VB, but you need to set the mime-type to text/html

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the mailbody is to be sent as HTML... like this:

```
objMail.BodyFormat = System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Html;
```

Comment: Just an FYI, the BodyFormat property is for a MailItem object, not MailMessage.